Is the differential of a harmonic function a harmonic function?
Let $f:M\to N$ be a harmonic map between two Riemanian manifolds
Is it an obvious question to ask:

Is $df:TM \to TN$ necessarily a harmonic map if we endow the tangent bundles with Sasakian metric

Is it a  theorem in some  book?If the  answer is  positive, are  there some proofs with some  approaches different from a  direct  computation methods(An indirect  but  innovative proof)

Have you tried to work this out for $f\colon M\to\Bbb R$?

@TedShifrin  Dear Prof. Shifrin  Thanks  for  your  attention.  No  I  did not compute   in details. But the  Laplacian of  a real  valued function is  indeed a  function so the  Laplacian of  derivative is the  derivative  of  Laplacian (I guess work in general  case): $d(\Delta f)=\Delta (df) $. For  every  manifold  the differential operator   commute  with  Laplace  operator  acting  on  differential  form  since $\Delta=dd^*+d^*d$. But what is  an  appropriate analogues  for action of  Laplacian  on  maps(instead of  differential forms)?

So  I think for  real  valued case the  answer is  affirmative.  Am  I  correct?

But  does the  problem  has  an affirmative  answer in its  full generality?

However  for  M  compact and  N=R  there is  no  harmonic  map unless  constant

@TedShifrin Maybe a complete answer can be found here?https://math.jhu.edu/~js/Math646/eells-sampson.pdf

@TedShifrin  My first purpose: Is it really a trivial question? Is it  worth of  research  or  work?

I wouldn’t call it trivial, but it’s something that every differential geometry learns. If you dig through standard textbooks on Riemannian geometry, such as the one by John Lee, you should be able to find the calculation for scalar functions. If you’re serious about learning Riemannian geometry, you should work through such a textbook.

You can post a question showing how far you are able to get with the calculation for a scalar function and ask for advice on how to proceed. There’s no point to asking about  harmonic maps until you understand the scalar function one.
